# Creating mouse over effect dynamicly

Tags: jquery

I am creating an photo gallery which can contain an random number of gallery items.
The code looks like:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
   <div id="gal-img1"><a href=""><img src="15.jpg"></a></div>
   <div class="gal-desc" id="gal-desc1"><h5>Title</h5></div>
</div> 
.........

<div class="gallery-item">
   <div id="gal-imgn"><a href=""><img src="15.jpg"></a></div>
   <div class="gal-desc" id="gal-descn"><h5>Title</h5></div>
</div>
```

The class 'gal-desc' has 'display' set to 'none' and on gal-img(1) to gal-img(n) mouseover I want to set the 'display' to 'block' of its corresponding gal-desc(1) to gal-desc(n).

I can insert manually the following code from 1 to 100 lets say but if i will get 40 gallery items i will have 60 mouseover unuseable. If i have 110 gallery items then 10 items wont have the desired effect.

```
$("#gal-img1").mouseover(function(){  
    $("#gal-desc1").css('display','block'); 
});
```

The maxim number of gallery items i get it with $("div[id^=gal-img]").length , but from here on i am stuck.

Can you please guys give me an ideea in which direction i must go.

Thank you.

Comment: you are going down the wrong road, ----> this <----- is your answer.  instead of using an id to select the element to change, use the class, and then refer to it as this.  I will show you an example in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target all the elements by using the same selector you are using to get the correct number of elements, and then inside the function use context to target just the `.gal-desc` element inside the hovered elements parent `.gallery-item` etc :

```
$("div[id^=gal-img]").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).closest('.gallery-item').find('.gal-desc').show();
});
```

or to toggle visiblity on mouseenter/leave

```
$("div[id^=gal-img]").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.gallery-item').find('.gal-desc').toggle(e.type=='mouseenter');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, maybe you are looking for some css? Something like:

```
.gallery-item > div:first-child:hover{display:block;}
```

Comment: frankly ... i would preffer css if it is simplyer than a jquery code ... I just want those description divs called gal-desc to be shown on any of the gallery-items mouseover event

Comment: Try .gallery-item:hover > div + div{display:block;}

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation, which is available in jQuery using $.on. Wrap all .gallery-items in a container to make it work like I did below with .gallery. This will allow for an infinite number of .gallery-items and is very performant.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <div id="gal-imgn"><a href=""><img src="15.jpg"></a></div>
        <div class="gal-desc" id="gal-descn"><h5>Title</h5></div>
    </div> 
    .....
</div>
.....
$('.gallery').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.gallery-item', function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).find('.gal-desc').show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.gal-desc').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking on your code i think its the same as the code above ... the code its good for me ... thank you

Comment: Not *quite* the same. This one uses event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<div id="gal-imgn">
```

to

```
<div class="gal-img">
```

then do this:

```
$(".gal-img").mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).next(".gal-desc").show(); 
});
```

additionally you can add mouseout like this:

```
$(".gal-img").mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).next(".gal-desc").show(); 
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next(".gal-desc").hide();
};
```

here is a jsfiddle of this (inefficient) code for fun.  http://jsfiddle.net/d27Nn/1/

Comment: Using this method has heavy performance costs (tying individual event handlers to possibly 100 items) and does not allow for dynamic DOM insertion.

Comment: interesting, I see your point Brian, I guess I develop for a small internal place so I don't think about performance as much.  I like Brians solution.

Comment: but Brian, you didnt make a nice JSFIDDLE to demo your solution.